# How to replace/remove the child class using parent ID or DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to remove the `abc class` in the `div` contained `just inside the "oneClass"` and replace it with another class name may be `"xyz"`, Note that I DO NOT want the `"abc class"` inside the `"twoClass"` to be replaced Can some one guide me how to achieve it?

```
<div class = "oneClass" id = "oneId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Phil
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="twoClass" id = "twoId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Heath
        </div>
    </div>
```

After applying jquery or javascript the output should be

```
<div class = "oneClass" id = "oneId">
        <div class = "xyz">  // CLASS NAME GOT CHANGED
            Phil
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="twoClass" id = "twoId">
        <div class = "abc">  // CLASS NAME REMAINES SAME
            Heath
        </div>
    </div>
```

Kindly guide me here.

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [child selector >](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) in jQuery to select the element with class `abc` directly under `oneClass`. Then simply [remove](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) the `abc` class and [add](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) the `xyz` class to it.

```js
$(".oneClass > .abc").removeClass("abc").addClass("xyz")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "oneClass" id = "oneId">
   <div class = "abc">
      Phil
   </div>
</div>

<div class ="twoClass" id = "twoId">
   <div class = "abc">
      Heath
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the id of the parent div.

```js
$('#oneID > .abc').removeClass('abc').addClass('xyz');
```

```js
$('#oneId > .abc').removeClass('abc').addClass('xyz');
```

```css
.xyz {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oneClass" id="oneId">
  <div class="abc">
    <!-- NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE Phil -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="twoClass" id="twoId">
  <div class="abc">
    <!-- NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE Heath -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('.oneClass');
var childEle = a.children();
Array.prototype.forEach.call(childEle,function(ele) {
    ele.classList = "xyz";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "oneClass" id = "oneId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Phil
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="twoClass" id = "twoId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Heath
        </div>
    </div>

        function find(){

            $('div#oneID').childern('div').addClass('success');

            $('div#oneID').childern('div').removeClass('success');

        };
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

`find`,`removeClass`  and `addClass`  do what you want like this.

```js
$('.oneClass').find('.abc').removeClass('abc').addClass('xyz');
```

```css
.xyz{
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "oneClass" id = "oneId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Phil
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="twoClass" id = "twoId">
        <div class = "abc">  // NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE
            Heath
        </div>
    </div>
```